# Creating Labels for Dates

Tags: r, label

I am working in R. I have a data frame that consists of Sampling Date and water temperature. I have provided a sample dataframe below:

```
  Date            Temperature
  2015-06-01      11
  2015-08-11      13
  2016-01-12      2
  2016-07-01      12
  2017-01-08      4
  2017-08-13      14
  2018-03-04      7
  2018-09-19      10
  2019-8-24       8
```

Due to the erratic nature of sampling dates (due to samplers ability to site) I am unable to classify years normally January 1 to December 31st and instead am using the beginning of the sampling period as the start of 1 year. In this case a year would start June 1st and End may 31st, that way I can accruately compare the years to one another. Thus I want 4 years to have the following labels

```
   Year_One = "2015-06-01" - "2016-05-31"
   Year_Two = "2016-06-01" - "2017-05-31"
   Year_Three = "2017-06-01" - "2018-05-31"
   Year_Four = "2018-06-01" - "2019-08-24"
```

My goal is to create an additional column with these labels but have thus far been unable to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create two columns year1 and year2 with two different approaches. The year2 approach needs that all the periods start june 1st and end may 31st  (in your code the year_four ends 2019-08-24) so it may not be exactly what you need:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dt$Date <- as.Date(dt$Date)

dt %>% 
  mutate(year1= case_when(between(Date, as.Date("2015-06-01") , as.Date("2016-05-31")) ~ "Year_One",
                              between(Date, as.Date("2016-06-01") , as.Date("2017-05-31")) ~ "Year_Two",
                              between(Date, as.Date("2017-06-01") , as.Date("2018-05-31")) ~ "Year_Three",
                              between(Date, as.Date("2018-06-01") , as.Date("2019-08-24")) ~ "Year_Four",
                              TRUE ~ "0")) %>% 
  mutate(year2 = paste0(year(Date-months(5)),"/", year(Date-months(5))+1))
```

The output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  Date       Temperature year1      year2    
  <date>           <dbl> <chr>      <chr>    
1 2015-06-01          11 Year_One   2015/2016
2 2015-08-11          13 Year_One   2015/2016
3 2016-01-12           2 Year_One   2015/2016
4 2016-07-01          12 Year_Two   2016/2017
5 2017-01-08           4 Year_Two   2016/2017
6 2017-08-13          14 Year_Three 2017/2018
7 2018-03-04           7 Year_Three 2017/2018
8 2018-09-19          10 Year_Four  2018/2019
9 2019-08-24           8 Year_Four  2019/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `strftime` to get the years, then make a `factor` with levels on the `unique` values. I'd recommend numbers instead of words, because they can be coded automatically. Else, use `labels=c("one", "two", ...)`.

```
d <- within(d, {
  year <- strftime(Date, "%Y")
  year <- paste("Year", factor(year, labels=seq(unique(year))), sep="_")
})
#          Date temperature   year
# 1  2017-06-01           1 Year_1
# 2  2017-09-01           2 Year_1
# 3  2017-12-01           3 Year_1
# 4  2018-03-01           4 Year_2
# 5  2018-06-01           5 Year_2
# 6  2018-09-01           6 Year_2
# 7  2018-12-01           7 Year_2
# 8  2019-03-01           8 Year_3
# 9  2019-06-01           9 Year_3
# 10 2019-09-01          10 Year_3
# 11 2019-12-01          11 Year_3
# 12 2020-03-01          12 Year_4
# 13 2020-06-01          13 Year_4
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17318, 17410, 17501, 17591, 
17683, 17775, 17866, 17956, 18048, 18140, 18231, 18322, 18414
), class = "Date"), temperature = 1:13), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```